# Trigger event when updating datepicker by restriction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker, knockout-3.0

I've got a jQuery UI datepicker which uses restrictions. The datepicker is initialized and bound to an input element using a knockout custom binding. These date restrictions are being handled by computeds which rely on other values in my form. The thing is: by setting the datepicker restrictions the DOM updates (visibly) to another value. However, the change event registered on that element does not trigger. I'm desperate to catch this event so I can update my observable accordingly.

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change', function() {
    console.log('this should fire when clicking the Set restrictions-button');
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    var value = $(element).datepicker('getDate');
    observable(value);
});
```

I created a pen just to illustrate the problem: http://codepen.io/Egidius/pen/XdyazR?editors=1011

By clicking the "Set restrictions"-button you see the date changing in the DOM. However the event does not trigger by that mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery UI datepicker doesn't trigger a change after it changes its value due to a new restriction. You can force it to do so by adding `.trigger("change")` or `.change()` to your `setRestrictions` method:

```
this.setRestrictions = function() {
   var minDate = new Date();
   minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 5);
   $("input[name='date']")
     .datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate)
     .trigger("change");
}
```

Also note that jQuery UI isn't very picky when triggering `onSelect`: it doesn't check if the value actually changed. It might be a nice feature to check this yourself in the change handler. Alternatively, you could check *before* triggering the change, but you'd still have to 'fix' the change triggers that happen when clicking an already selected date.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much user3297291 :). Although it wasn't the fix I was hoping for it does the job! Still leaves me wondering where the date update I see happening in my DOM is being handled.